# Buying and Reading Books without Kindle or Nooks apps

Tags: ebooks, kindle-for-android, nook-for-android

I want buy an e-book (theleanstartup.com)  and read on my tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab) .  Ebook is available for kindle and nook.  Also there is an Amazon link (probably kindle version).  There isn't pdf download option,  ofcourse.

Kindle and Nook's Android apps isn't downloadable for Turkey.

How can i buy and read this book?  Any ideas?

Comment: In addition to asking here, you may also want to go directly to Amazon.  They have a vested interest in helping you buy their merchandise.

Comment: i tried this.  getting same error.  its not downloadable from Turkey.

Comment: ' We could not process your order because of geographical restrictions on the product which you were attempting to purchase. Please refer to the terms of use for this product to determine the geographical restrictions.

We apologize for any inconvenience this may have caused you.'

Comment: @Eray Oh, so this is purely a purchasing question, not an Android question.  We can't help you with that, sorry :(

Comment: @Matthew it's just for Amazon.  But there are a lots of services / solutions.  Because of this,  i'm asking here.

Comment: If you're able to buy it somewhere and have trouble getting it onto your device, that might be on-topic, but the actual purchase is not; it has to be Android-specific, and we don't do shopping questions regardless.  (See the [FAQ].)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Amazon Appstore from [here](http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/get-appstore/android) and install it directly, and install the Kindle app from there instead of from the Play Store.

Comment: i tried this.  getting same error.  its not downloadable from Turkey.

Comment: > We could not process your order because of geographical restrictions on the product which you were attempting to purchase. Please refer to the terms of use for this product to determine the geographical restrictions.

We apologize for any inconvenience this may have caused you.